# Operand data type varchar(max) is invalid for divide operator

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

Below is the query I am trying to run using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio:

```
update [SG report] 
set [percentage_paid] = ([Savings This Season (All)] / [Savings Goal Amount]) * 100
```

Comment: Your code is not valid SQL.  Please provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you want to do.

Comment: [SG report] - database table,
[percent_paid] - column name,
[Savings This Season (All)] - column name,
[Savings Goal Amount] - column name 

Datatype for columns is varchar(max)

NB: Am using microsoft sql server management studio 18

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One or both of your values are strings.  Use `try_convert()` to convert them to an appropriate type.  The specific type is not clear, but something like:

```
update [SG report] 
    set [percentage_paid] =  (try_convert(float, [Savings This Season (All)])  * 100 /
                              try_convert(float, [Savings Goal Amount])
                             );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
update [SG report] 
set [percentage_paid] =  ([Savings This Season (All)] / [Savings Goal Amount]) * 100
where isnumeric([Savings This Season (All)])=1 and isnumeric([Savings Goal Amount])=1
```

Comment: `ISNUMERIC` is a terrible function. It gives both false positives and negatives. Considering that `TRY_CONVERT` and `TRY_CAST` are available in every supported version of SQL Server, there's no reason to not use them.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try with best answer for next question.@Larnu